# UIImageView fade animation with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, nstimer

I have a Horizontal `UICollectionView` with *n* number of records. Each cell has an `UIImageView` which needs to animate the Fadein Fadeout with some TimerInterval. So, i have planned to implement that reload my `UICollectionView` using `NSTimer` My code snippet,

```
....
....
if (collectionTimer) {
    [collectionTimer invalidate];
    collectionTimer = nil;
}
collectionTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(reloadCollection) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
....
....
```

*reloadCollection* Method

```
-(void)reloadCollection{
    [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

*cellForItemAtIndexPath* Method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ....
    ....
    /* Basic Animation working fine*/
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        cell.articleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [images objectAtIndex:i]]];
    } completion:nil];

    /* Not working */
    /* [UIView transitionWithView:cell.articleImage duration:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
        cell.articleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [images objectAtIndex:i]]];
    } completion:nil]; */
    ....
    ....
}
```

The basic animation works fine. But, whenever i am trying to implement `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve` with `transitionWithView` method. It will showing the animation, but immediately one more image loaded because of `reloadData` calling. How to fix this? How to animate only the images in `UICollectionView`

Any Idea appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My animation work like this:

```
cell.articleImage.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
     [cell.articleImage setAlpha:1.0];
}];
```

Comment: Tried with Alpha rates. Not working properly. I want to use exact animation. Not using by Alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the animation for visible cells without reloading the collectionView:

```
NSArray* visibleCells = [collectionView visibleCells];
[visibleCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UICollectionViewCell* cell, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //TODO: add animation;
}];
```

*Update*
To animate new cells, you should start animation after adding cell to window. In cell you can override method didMoveToWindow:

```
- (void)didMoveToWindow
{
   [super didMoveToWindow];
   if (self.window && self.shouldStartAnimation)
   {
     [self startAnimation];
   }
}
```

And in ViewController these methods:

```
    - (void)animateVisibleCells
    {
        NSArray* visibleCells = [self.collectionView visibleCells];
        [visibleCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(BTCollectionViewCell* cell, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [cell startAnimation];
        }];
    }


    #define ANIMATION_DURATION (0.3)
    - (void)animateCells
    {
        self.shouldAnimationStart = YES;

        [self animateVisibleCells];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:ANIMATION_DURATION target:self selector:@selector(endAnimateCells) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }


    - (void)endAnimateCells
    {
        self.shouldAnimationStart = NO;
    }


    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        ((BTCollectionViewCell*)cell).shouldStartAnimation = self.shouldAnimationStart;
    }
```

But problem with synchronization of the animation continues to be (new animations will starts from 0 time). If you know method to start animation from concrete time, you can use it method in willDisplayCell

Comment: Its working. But, whenever i scroll it. Same time images not animated. Like timer has splitted.

Answer (score -1):

Well i guess that in your method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you are not configuring animation right.

please use this.

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.1 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
    cell.articleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [images objectAtIndex:i]]];
} completion:nil];
```

You were not assigning the delay properly to let animation work.

Hope it works for you now. Thanks

Comment: then try changing alpha value within animation block.

Comment: [Already tried](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605773/uiimageview-fade-animation-with-uicollectionview/28605985?noredirect=1#comment45516371_28606007)

Comment: please provide some code where you already used this by using alpha values.

Comment: Exact code like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28606007/940096) I have just added the code which will set new image after setting Alpha to `1.0`

Comment: 0.3 is vary small time to see animation, try increasing time and set alpha as view.alpha += 1.0;